# Installing Specific Docker Version via Puppet

Tags: docker, ubuntu, puppet, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04

While deploying docker using puppet, I encounter an interesting issue.

docker installs fine if I use: `version => latest`
docker install fails if I use: `version => '20.10.16'`

My setup is as follows:
puppet master is `Ubuntu 20.04`.
puppet agent is `Ubuntu 22.04` (on which I am trying to install docker).

I believe puppet docker module supports this setup.

The version lines I tried: 
`version => '20.10.16'` 
`version => '20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu'` 
`version => '20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-jammy'`

The error I get when I specify a specific version is as follows:

```bash
Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install docker-ce=20.10.16' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  docker-ce-cli
```

Anyone has any idea what can be done so that it installs specific version of docker instead of the latest one?

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When running `apt-cache madison docker-ce` it appears that the version number is `5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-jammy`.
Running `apt install docker-ce=20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-jammy` returns the same error as yours, but `apt install docker-ce=5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-jammy` works.
I suggest trying with the `5:` in front of the version number.